# Summing the sum from two seperate tables

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, group-by, sum

I have the following query:

```
select    tb1.accountnum, to_char(tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY'),
          sum(tb3.amt_due)
from      db_table1 tb1, db_table2 tb2, db_table3 tb3
where     tb1.acctnum  = tb2.acctnum  and
          tb2.acctcode = tb3.acctcode and
          tb3.type_id  = 10           and
          tb1.status   = 'YES'
group by  tb1.accountnum, (tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY'),
having    sum(tb3.amt_due) < 0;
```

This query will sum the amount due for each month separately and if negative, return the account number. For example:

```
accountnum |   Month   |  Amt_Due
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    15
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |   -20
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Mar    |     3
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Aug    |    13
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Dec    |   -25
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Dec    |    40
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

Will give the result:

```
accountnum |   Month   |  Amt_Due
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -5
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

I now want to add an additional table (tb4) and sum the charges as we just did above. Consider these rows in the new table (tb4).

```
accountnum |   Month   |  misc_charge
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -45
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |     25
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Sep    |     -7
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

Summing the charges would give us the result:

```
accountnum |   Month   |  misc_charge
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -20
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Sep    |     -7
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

Now I want to sum the results of our first query to the results of the second. So:

```
accountnum |   Month   |  Amt_Due
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -5
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

Summed with

```
accountnum |   Month   |  misc_charge
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -20
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Sep    |     -7
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

Gives a final result of:

```
accountnum |   Month   |  sum(sum(tb3.amt_due) + sum(tb4.misc_charge))
---------- | --------- | ---------
      1    |    Jan    |    -25
---------- | --------- | ---------
      2    |    Sep    |     -7
---------- | --------- | ---------
```

I modified my original query to include tb4, but Oracle gives me the error:
*ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply*

```
select    tb1.accountnum, to_char(tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY'),
          to_char(tb4.month, 'MON, YYY'), 
          sum(sum(tb3.amt_due) + sum(tb4.misc_charge))
from      db_table1 tb1, db_table2 tb2, db_table3 tb3, db_table4 tb4
where     tb1.acctnum  = tb2.acctnum  and
          tb2.acctcode = tb3.acctcode and
          tb3.acctcode = tb4.acctcode and
          tb3.type_id  = 10           and
          tb1.status   = 'YES'
group by  tb1.accountnum, to_char(tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY'),
          to_char(tb4.month, 'MON, YYY')
having    sum(sum(tb3.amt_due) + sum(tb4.misc_charge)) < 0;
```

Can someone please help me with the syntax of including the final table?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not share what you tried?

Comment: Added the modifications I tried!

Comment: I can't follow your entire process (too late in the day), but: if you group by account and month and select the sum of amounts, separately in two row sets (be they base tables, views, subqueries, the result of joins etc.) - why can't you do a UNION ALL of the row sets, *relevant columns only*, BEFORE any group by and sum, and THEN apply the grouping and aggregate function to the result of UNION ALL? That would be both cleaner (easier to write and to follow for future developers maintaining the code) and more efficient.

Comment: @mathguy. Isn't that what I did? ;)

Comment: @BobC - I didn't read your solution closely, but in it I see, in the first branch of the UNION ALL, a "group by" and a `sum(amt_due)`. Is that needed there? Can't it wait till after the UNION ALL? I am not necessarily saying it can, but that's what went through my mind.

Comment: @mathguy. Actually I think it's the other way around - I am missing a group by in the second UNION-ALL branch (which I will now fix!) - at least that is what I meant to do. I think early aggregation will be beneficial from a performance perspective too. However, I will look at your late aggregation suggestion...

Comment: @mathguy. For my test data, the late group-by gives the same results. I guess it would depend upon how much aggregation reduces the rows would dictate which approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to have something like this. I have not tested it with your data/tables, so see if this works.

```
select accountnum, month, sum(amt)                                                           
from                                                                                         
(                                                                                            
  select    tb1.accountnum, to_char(tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY') month,                           
            sum(tb3.amt_due) amt                                                             
  from      db_table1 tb1, db_table2 tb2, db_table3 tb3                                      
  where     tb1.acctnum  = tb2.acctnum  and                                                  
            tb2.acctcode = tb3.acctcode and                                                  
            tb3.type_id  = 10           and                                                  
            tb1.status   = 'YES'                                                             
  group by  tb1.accountnum, (tb3.month, 'MON, YYYY')                                         
  union all                                                                                  
  select tb4.accountnum, to_char(tb4.month, 'MON, YYYY'),                                    
            sum(tb4.misc_charge)                                                             
  from tb4 
  group by tb4.accountnum, to_char(tb4.month, 'MON, YYYY')                                                                                  
)                                                                                            
group by accountnum, month                                                                   
having sum(amt) < 0
```